# Cannot find name of module loaded with require()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am pulling in a Javascript file at the top of the React file (I am using Typescript by the way):

```
let FloDialog = require('../public/js/flo-dialog.min');
```

Then there is a property for this dialog class:

```
dialog: FloDialog = null;
```

Notice that the type should be FloDialog. That is the name of the prototype object contained in the module.

Then in the constructor I initialize the dialog like so:

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.dialog = new FloDialog({
        effect: {
            fade: true
        },
        position: 'fixed'
    });
}
```

And later on I call a function on this dialog prototype object to open a dialog. 
This code does work, **but I am getting a Typescript error**: TS2304: Cannot find name 'FloDialog'. On the `dialog: FloDialog = null;` line.

The module file looks like this:

```
var FloDialog=function(t){this.id=Date.now(),this.cloak=this.renderCloakHtml()...etc..etc... (minified code)

if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && typeof module.exports !== 'undefined') {
    module.exports = FloDialog;
}
```

So I export the prototype object as a module. I include it with a require() function. Why isn't the type recognized on line `dialog: FloDialog = null;` and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The type `FloDialog` is not defined. You don't have a `../public/js/flo-dialog.min.d.ts` to describe what should it look like.

Comment: How would that .d.ts look for this file: https://github.com/Code-Stars/flo-dialog/blob/master/src/flo-dialog.js?